# sending mail to multiple recipients upto 50 in laravel

Tags: laravel, email

I want to send email to multiple recipients up to 50 at a time which is entered through the text field. how I can send it to multiple recipients at one click.how to get the all email address into one variable and how to send it to multiple recipients.

Controller:-

```
\Mail::send('emails.contact',
array(                 
'email' => $request->get('email'),                 
'sub' => $request->get('sub'),
'bodyMessage' => $request->get('message'),
), function($message) use ($request)
{
$message->from('harsha1604gandhi@gmail.com');
$message->to($request->get('email'));
$message->subject($request->sub);
});
```

**View:-**

```
<input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" name="email" 
multiple>
```

Answer (score 0):

**How to get the all email address**

I see two ways to  do this. The first is creating one `<input>` to each email. It's something like this:

```
<input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" name="emails[]" >
<input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" name="emails[]" >
```

The `[]` in the name is important because this turn the inputs into an array with name `email`.

The second way is using just one input. But for this way do you need use js. I suggest you see:

[Jquery solution only for this](https://www.jqueryscript.net/form/email-multiple.html)

[A library to manipulate selects](https://select2.org/tagging#tagging-with-multi-value-select-boxes)

Particularly I use this library by disabling dropdown

**How send emails to all recipients**

Once you have all the emails, you just need to interate over the request variable with store this values.
Something like this

```
foreach($request->('emails') as $email){
        \Mail::send('emails.contact',
    array(                 
     'email' => $email,                 
     'sub' => $request->get('sub'),
     'bodyMessage' => $request->get('message'),
  ), function($message) use ($request)
  {
       $message->from('harsha1604gandhi@gmail.com');
       $message->to($email);
       $message->subject($request->sub);
    });
}
```

Comment: why two input text boxes

Comment: Two input text boxes is an exemple of multiples input.

Comment: Verifiy if the $request->email is a array

Comment: **return $allemails=$request->get('emails')** It returns me the following output:-                        
                                   "test@gmail.com ,test123@gmail.com"

Comment: mail perfectly goes to 1 person but when send to multiple recipients the error comes

Comment: the emails must be an array